# Lego EV3 doesn't respond to direct command

Tags: ev3

I tried to execute command (via bt) play tone:

```
play_tone = '\x0F\x00\x00\x00\x80\x00\x00\x94\x01\x81\x02\x82\xE8\x03\x82\xE8\x03'
# send commands to EV3 via bluetooth
with open('/dev/tty.EV3-SerialPort', 'w', 0) as bt:
    bt.write(play_tone)
```

or start program “Demo” on EV3 brick

```
run_demo = '\x30\x00\x00\x00\x80\x08\x00\xC0\x08\x82\x01\x00\x84\x2E\x2E\x2F\x70\x72\x6A\x73\x2F\x42\x72\x6B\x50\x72\x6F\x67\x5F\x53\x41\x56\x45\x2F\x44\x65\x6D\x6F\x2E\x72\x70\x66\x00\x60\x64\x03\x01\x60\x64\x00'
```

but nothing happens. No error in python script. Wireless connection status (EV3 brick display) show connected during script execution.

OS X 10.9.4, Python 2.7.5, EV3

Answer (score 1):

Both of your examples are working for me. In the Bluetooth settings on the EV3, make sure "iPhone/iPad/iPod" is *not* checked.

Comment: Unchecking "iPhone/iPad/iPod" do the trick. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please consider accepting David Lechner's answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Hi, as Kramii states, it would be really beneficial for everyone if you can accept Davids answer (click the little check mark below the vote count) - David and you will both get some rep, and other people will know what worked for you :)

Comment: Vote up requires 15 reputation... which I do not have